# Azure web app creatings web.config automatically when doing local-git deployment, breaking app (adds unneeded settings)

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple HTML/JS/CSS project (*not Node*).  I create a brand new azure web app, and set its deployment option to "local git". I then follow the instructions about [Local Git Deployment to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git), running `git remote add azure https://<my-user-name>@localgitreprosite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/LocalGitReproSite.git`>.  And I push to the repo (`git push azure master`)

The problem is that Azure (or more specifically, the deployment engine that runs when doing a git push) sees that my file is named "app.js", and assumes that it's a node deployment.  It then generates a web.config.  You can see it right in the logs:

```
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Deleting file: 'hostingstart.html'
remote: Copying file: '.gitignore'
<... remote: Copying file>
remote: Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
remote: Using start-up script app.js
remote: Generated web.config.
remote: The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
remote: The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 6.9.1.
remote: Selected npm version 3.10.8
<... etc>
```

And when it does, the site returns a 500 error, because `web.config` adds an `iisnode` handler and a bunch of other unneeded stuff, which is not relevant for simple html/js/css resources.

How can I **suppress this `web-config`-creation behavior** (or maybe more broadly, this auto-guessing of what project I'm doing), and make the deployment work as is?  Is there a configuration I can do via the Portal or via a .deployment file that could tell Azure not to guess?

My project structure is super simple:

[image]

I realize that "app.js" is a common Node pattern, but it's also a reasonably common single-page-app pattern.  So while it's true that I could probably change the name of "app.js" to something else, I'd rather not have this artificial limitation...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this appsetting `SCM_SCRIPT_GENERATOR_ARGS=--basic`. See [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#taking-over-the-script-generator-command-line) for details.

You may need to manually delete the `web.config` on the already deployed app.

Ot if you want full control over the deployment process, you can move to using a [custom deployment script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/), which lets you control everything that happens.

Comment: That worked -- though it had the (maybe obvious, though not desirable in my case) effect of no longer doing `npm install`.  In my ideal world, I would still want an `npm install`, just not starting of the node configuration.  I tried (briefly) to get `npm install` working in the `.deployment` file, but it didn't seem to work easily (neither by itself nor as part of a powershell command)

I think what I may end up doing is creating my own web.config, and that way I don't get an automatically-created one.  Or alternatively move my deployed files into a "public" subfolder -- will experiment.

Comment: I expanded my answer to cover this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your 500 error is probably not from web.config being dropped. App Services runs Node.js apps using iisnode, hence web.config is dropped there with startup configuration for your Node app so that iisnode knows to run app.js in your root. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started-cli-nodejs#how-app-service-deploys-your-nodejs-app).

That link also has a section that shows you how to debug your HTTP 500.

Comment: If I remove the web.config, the files get served as regular html/js/css files, and everything works.  So it still feels like a bug / undesired behavior, that I'd still like to know how to work around.  (Note that if the files were in a subfolder rather than at the root, it would also work.  So the problem is with the `web.config` at the root)